# Glut and Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl, interface-builder, glut

I would like to create an application with multiple views in XCode 4 for Mac, one of them which should display OpenGL.
Using Interface Builder, can I use the standard OpenGL view and still use Glut to program and display in this view ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

No, GLUT is a minimalistic framework, not to be used in serious applications or be mixed with other frameworks. As long as your GLUT applications just uses the canonical *display, reshape, keyboard, mouse* callback handlers, just call these from your GLView Cocoa code in your implementation of the interface.

Comment: Thanks. So I should rather be focussing standard OpenGL code, right ?

Comment: GLUT is not part of OpenGL; there's nothing special about GLUT, it's just another way of creating and dealing with an OpenGL window. Just use OpenGL as usual.

Comment: I indeed worked on OpenGL yesterday and it seems much more easy than expected (at least the basics). Thanks for the given direction !